# Minecraft modpack - Resurrection FTB - Player was boiled alive death message

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

The is related to the specific modpack Resurrection on the FTB launcher. My friend is taking random damage with no apparent reason and the death message of "< Player > was boiled alive". No debuff was shown on the player. Anyone knows what the cause of this damage is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely due to the player holding a lava bucket in their inventory.I suspect it is due to the overhaul in gregtech which caused this to happen.

Comment: Cheers to the grammar corrections